# how to access tag slider value in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

i have a question regarding slider tags. Lets assume i have a slider and its tag is "1", how can i get the .value of slider that has tag '1'? I saw examples of if(slider.tag ==1) but i want to access the value of it - how is this possible? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
value = [[yourView viewWithTag:1] value];
```

I recommend to wire up the slider through a property and access it directly, though, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `viewWithTag:` method on the superview:

```
UISlider *slider1 = [slidersView viewWithTag:1];
if (slider1) {
    NSLog(@"Value of slider 1: %f", slider1.value);
}
```